# In-explicit constructing in operator overloading?

Tags: c++, constructor, construction

Is it possible use in-explicit constructing with operators ?
Just like in this example (which does of course not work):

```
class myFoo {
    public:
        double x, y;

        myFoo(double, double);

        void    operator [] (myFoo);
};

int main() {
    myFoo f1(0.0, 1.1);
    f1[ {9.9, 10.0} ];          /// or whatever syntax to use, does not work
    f1.operator[] ( {9.9, 10.0} ); /// works !
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++11 allows an initializer list to be passed to an overloaded `operator []` (see 13.5.5).

You'd need something like

```
void operator[](std::initializer_list<double>);
```

That would match your original syntax of `f1[ {9.9, 10.0} ];`.

Comment: but `f1.operator[] ( {9.9, 10.0} );` works without initializer lists?

Comment: Good point. I have no idea why the difference. It might depend on what "works" means, and what compiler is being used.

Answer (score 1):

hmm...

`f1[myFoo(9.9, 10.0)];` ?

requires a reasonably sane `operator[]` (i.e. expects a `const myFoo&` to bind to the temporary).

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible using `operator []` in current C++03 or upcoming C++11 standard. However, you can exploit `operator []` with some weird syntax to achieve the same:

```
f1[myFoo(9.9,10.0)];
```

where the `operator []` is as,

```
myFoo& operator [] (const myFoo&);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it does work with the current code. Whatever might be your implementation with the '[]' (all I have done is to return the value at the index in an array inside a class. So the class can now be used as an array type) operator all that needs to be done to make sure that you pass in a const reference and make no changes are done.

```
int main() {
    myFoo f1(0.0, 1.1);
    f1[f1];      /// or whatever syntax to use
}
```

Will work.

Comment: `f1[ {9.9, 10.0} ];`  He appears to want to pass an initializer list

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in C++11 (g++ Version 4.5.2). You just have to say

```
f1[myFoo {9.9, 10.0} ];
```

instead of

```
f1[ {9.9, 10.0} ];
```